# Apache Directory listing

Tags: apache, webserver

I simply wan't to disable Directory listing on my Apache webserver (which mostly has just the default settings) and still be able to access files with direct links.

What is the easiest way to do this ?

Thanks in Advance.

gr

Comment: I simply removed Indexes from the .conf and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess with this:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however i already did it by editing the config and deleting indexes. thanks anyway !